# Enhanced for loop for Strings

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am a beginner to coding. Currently I am learning arrays.

In the following code, I am trying to display the words entered by the user using a `String` array. The code is displaying `null` when using enhanced for-loop. Can anyone explain the problem?

The code is working fine with normal for-loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String word;
    int count = 0;

    String[] words = new String[100];

    System.out.println("Enter the words (enter 'done' when finished):");

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter word "+ (count+1));
        word=scanner.nextLine();

        if (!word.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
            words[count]=word;
            count++;
        }
    }while (!word.equalsIgnoreCase("done"));

    System.out.println("Words entered are:");

    for (String print:words){
        System.out.println(print);
    }

    scanner.close();
}
```

The code should display the words entered by the user but it is displaying `null` instead of the word.

Comment: As you are a beginner, I assume you haven't learned about `ArrayList` yet. When you learn it, you'll see that `ArrayList` will be better suited than an array in this case. It's used when you don't know exactly how many elements you will need.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException   Yeah, and then there is linked list too. It is very confusing to choose the right list at this point.

Comment: It's a performance-based decision. In most cases, ArrayList will be faster. Don't worry too much about it. Just use ArrayList for now. If at some point you start writing performance-critical applications, you'll probably know by then, how to measure performance to determine which one is best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enhanced for loop is not suitable in this case, since it is printing all 100 elements of the array, most of which are probably `null`.

When you use the regular for loop, you take advantage of the `count` variable, which lets you print only the initialized elements of the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    System.out.println(words[i]);
}
```

If you insist on using the enhanced for loop, you can check for `null` elements, and break from the loop when you encounter the first:

```
for (String print:words){
    if (print != null) {
        System.out.println(print);
    } else {
        break; // once you encountered the first null, there's no point to continue the loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've made an array with 100 entries.  Initially, all 100 of them are null.  Then, your do/while loop fills in a few of them.  How many depends on the user, of course.

But then, you're printing all 100 entries of the array.  You'll see a few words, then lots of nulls.  You might be better to print only the entries that *aren't* null, like this.

```
for (String print:words){
    if (print != null) {
        System.out.println(print);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely it does print the words entered by the user. You are seeing `null` because the size of your array is 100.

```
String[] words = new String[100];
```

Scroll up in your console to see the names originally entered by the user. You see *nulls* because the remaining elements in the array are `null`. For eg: if the user enters *5 words* the remaining *95 words* in the array are `null`.

You can add a null check to print out only the non-null values.

```
for (String print : words) {
    if (print != null) {
        System.out.println(print);
    }
}
```

If you are using `java-8`, you could just do :

```
Arrays.stream(words).filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(System.out::println);
```